# LinkedIn button shows up intermitent

Tags: button, cross-domain, linkedin-api

I am using the code to place a linkedIn Follow button (generated here https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company) on this page, http://new.janeirodigital.com (view Client Testimonials section). However, the buttons sometimes show up and sometimes don't.

I have read a little bit of cross domains issues that may cause this, but I am not able to find a workaround to fix this. If you visit that page in Chrome and see the errors console, you'll see a couple of errors like regarding the linked in button, like:

Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame with URL mysite.com from frame with URL http://platform.linkedin.com/js/....Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Has anybody experienced this problem before?

Any help appreciated
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that this is happening when there are more than one follow button on the page, if you delete the first one and the second shows without problems but the others have the same problem...

Hope this could help your team Jeremy!!

Answer (score 2):

The messages you are seeing in the developer console in Chrome are unrelated to your problem. They are an artifact of the cross-domain communication and as you'll notice, you see them for Facebook and Twitter as well on the same page.

That said, viewing your page I am also seeing intermittent 403s for some of the backend calls that the FollowCompany plugin is making. I have alerted our NOC to the issue and they should be investigating now.

Reviewing your page, it seems you have done everything necessary and are set, so once we fix the operational issue you should be good to go.

My apologies for any inconvenience!

-Jeremy